# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named after calling a script from another script

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, package

Assume I have the following file structure:

```
  Package/
           __init__.py
           A.py
  B.py
```

Inside `__init__.py` I have the following:

```
__init__.py/
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
```

Then I issue the following in the A.py script:

```
A.py/
from Package import *
```

However, I receive an error message that no module name Package is defined.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named Package
```

I thought `from Package import *` means running everything in the `__init__.py`.

I can run the A.py content and use the **init** import from B.py as I expected.(using `from Package import *`)

I am using VSCode and Anaconda and my OS is Windows 10.

I can append the project folder every time to my PythonPath using the following commands:

```
sys.path.append("Path to the Package")
```

But I do not want to run this piece of code every time.

Can anyone explain what is the problem?
Is this a new problem in Python since I do not recall having such issues in the past?

Comment: `A.py` is supposedly inside `Package` (i.e. part of the package), then inside it you try to star import everything from `Package`. This is not going to work and even if it did it will cause circular import. Not to mention that star imports are bad.

Comment: OK. The circular package might be an issue but this is not the case here. However why my command is not working.  How can I use what I imported have inside __init__.py then? This should be a new thing since this was not a problem while ago.

Comment: Check your `sys.path`. Python is searching the `Package` at places listed there. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 1):

Because if you run the `B.py`, the `Parent folder of Package folder` will be added into the `sys.path`, be equal to you add `sys.path.append("Path to the Package")` in the `A.py` file.

But when you run the `A.py`, it will add the `Package folder` instead of the `Parent folder of Package folder` to the `sys.path`.

**[sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys%20path#sys.path):**

> A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules.
> Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an
> installation-dependent default.
>
> As initialized upon program startup, **the first item of this list,**
> **path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to**
> **invoke the Python interpreter.**

If you are running the python file in debug mode(F5), and the `Package folder` was the subfolder of your workspace, you can configure the `PYTHONPATH` in the launch.json file:

```
  "env": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

In your A.py script use just use import file.py and do not use the star. Or, put all your files in a second Package2 directory and use from Package2 import * from your current A.py file.